# Proof Verification: There exist no largest prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers

I know it's probably a well known problem, but my intention to post/publish this question (and of course my approach) here is to verify my intuition about about the proof .Thus I done it, my way and honestly I don't know whether I had copied someone's approach or not.

**To prove that there is no largest prime**, *my approach* is as follows:

Suppose there is a largest prime $p\in \mathcal P$ (set of all primes) i.e. $p=\sup\mathcal P$.

Since there are prime/primes $> 2$, let there be a largest prime $p>2$.

Now every prime except 2 is an odd number, and the difference between two odd numbers is always even.  So for every $p_i \in \mathcal P/\{2\}$ there exists a $k \in \Bbb N$ such that $p_i+2k \in \mathcal P$. Which implies $p+2k\in \mathcal P$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$.

Which is a contradiction. Because $p+2k>p$, but we claimed $p$ is the largest member of $\mathcal P$.

So there exists no largest prime number.  □

Please let me know my faults, if any, and suggest improvements, if any.

Comment: The mistake in this proof is the fact that this statement can't be justified without the theorem you seek to prove: So every $p_i\in\mathcal P/\{2\}$ there exist a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $p_i+2k\in\mathcal P$. (Good try though)

Comment: Nowhere have you used any divisibility property, so you have not actually used the fact that these are primes. The only thing you have used is their oddness, which is not something unique to primes.

Comment: @RushabhMehta got it .. thank you very much.

Comment: This is a Proof by Blind Optimism. You haven't actually used any properties of the primes, except that most of them are odd. But there are many finite sets of odd numbers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not correct, because you haven't justified why for every odd prime $p_i$ there is a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $p_i+2k\in\mathcal P$. It is true that *if* there is a prime larger than an odd prime, then their difference must be even. However, how do you know that for each odd prime there is a larger prime?—that is exactly what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @DebjitMullick: No problem, Debjit! I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: of course... I'm thinking about it a bit differently... I'll discuss it with you after I get to an extent.

Comment: @DebjitMullick: How's it going? Have you thought more about how you can prove the theorem? As TonyK mentions in the comments, you need to use an essential property of primes (e.g. that every number has a prime factorisation) to prove this theorem, and that is true regardless of whether or not you use proof by contradiction.

Comment: I'm still on it .